# How to update a setup table only through Key => Value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a settings table built in the following way (I keep here the code short, for simplicity):

```
 ID |   key  |  value  |  category
-----------------------------------------
1   |  key_a | value_a |  geolocal
2   |  key_b | value_b |  geolocal
3   |  key_c | value_c |  geolocal
4   |  key_d | value_d |  opengraph
5   |  key_e | value_e |  opengraph
```

I read this table through a php/html page with the goal, to be able to update the above settings

```
<?
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'include/setup.php';

if (!empty($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == "UPDATE") {
    ...
    ... I EXPLAIN THIS CODE, WHICH SHOULD WORK ONLY WHEN "SUBMIT" IS CLICKED, BELOW.
    ...

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM setup";
$sth = sql->prepare($query);
$sth->execute;

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ${$row[$param]} = $row[$value];
?>
...
...
...
<div id="tabs-1">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="tab">
            <p><label for="key_a">KEY 1</label><input name="key_a" value="<? echo $key_a; ?>" size="50"/></p>
            <p><label for="key_b">KEY 2</label><input name="key_b" value="<? echo $key_b; ?>" size="50"/></p>
            <p><label for="key_c">KEY 3</label><input name="key_c" value="<? echo $key_c; ?>" size="50"/></p>
            <p><label for="key_d">KEY 4</label><input name="key_d" value="<? echo $key_d; ?>" size="50"/></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE"><input type="reset" value="RESET">
    </form>
</div>
...
...
...
<?
} // END While
?>
```

key_a, key_b etc are just examples.
In the reality, are called like:

```
app_secret
artist_name
token_page_access
etc etc ...
```

Thus, when I update the values, I have to create the following queries for each entry (the code I referred above):

```
$query="UPDATE setup SET value = $_POST['key_a'] WHERE key = key_a";
$query="UPDATE setup SET value = $_POST['key_b'] WHERE key = key_b";
$query="UPDATE setup SET value = $_POST['key_c'] WHERE key = key_c";
$query="UPDATE setup SET value = $_POST['key_d'] WHERE key = key_d";
```

As I said, I have not only 4 values on this tables, but almost 150.

Is there a way to simplify the UPDATE query, so that the code is simplified and more effective?

Comment: use arrays both in the form and in the php, then loop it to build a prepared query.

Comment: which api is used to connect with here?

Comment: I used PDO. However I applied the solution given by @Rajdeep Paul and it works perfectly (remind to change 'key' word, because it's a reserved word :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current scenario, you should loop through `$_POST` superglobal array to perform the `UPDATE` operations, like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == "UPDATE") {
    $query = "UPDATE `setup` SET `value` = :value WHERE `key` = :key";
    $sth = $sql->prepare($query);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if($key != 'submit'){
            $sth->execute(array(':value'=>$_POST[$key], ':key'=>$key));
        }
    }
}
```

**Sidenote:** `key` is a reserved word and `value` is a keyword in MySQL. You should always encapsulate your table and column names with backticks, just to be on the safe side. [**Keywords and Reserved Words in MySQL**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: After I forgot to change "key" with the real name on the table :D it worked PERFECTLY ... thanks a million :)

Comment: Rajdeep; they're using a mysql reserved word here; `key`. I think you know what to do about that ;-) the answers needs to be updated, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, indeed :D but I didn't pay attention in the first instance :) however now it's up and running thanks to your help

Comment: @TormyVanCool Ah, that's probably because `value` is a keyword and `key` is a reserved word in MySQL. You should encapsulate your table and column names in backticks. I've updated my answer, please test your application with the updated code snippet. Edit: Didn't see your comments above. Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: `value` is a keyword, not reserved. Only `key` is reserved (in mysql). That should have been included in the answer, not just updated, again IMHO ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html, `key` is mentioned as `KEY(R)` i.e. reserved word and `value` is mentioned as just `VALUE` i.e. keyword, or am I missing anything here?

Comment: `value` is a keyword; `values` is reserved. `value` does not need to be ticked, unless it's seen as being used as a method.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, actually I encapsulated both the table and column names with backticks just to be on the safe side. :-)